# How to uninstall nodejs from ubuntu20.04?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I was trying to create a react app and then I got an error like this:

> A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
>
> Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.
>
> You can fix this by running npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app before using create-react-app again.

I thought my Node.js version was not compatible with the present react-app version so I decided to uninstall Node.js and install latest version. Then I used below commands to uninstall Node.js:

1. `sudo npm uninstall create-react-app -g`
2. `npx clear-npx-cache`
3. `sudo apt-get remove nodejs`
4. `sudo apt-get purge nodejs`
5. `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Even though I tried to uninstall, when I search for the Node.js version it's showing like this:

```
$ node -v
v14.4.0
```

[image: Node version after uninstalling]

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong and what I need to do to uninstall the present version and install the latest version?

Comment: `nodejs` is the legacy node app I think. Try also removing `node`, note that this only works if you installed node using a node repo for ubuntu (I don't think one comes enabled by default). If you didn't then you need to uninstall based on how you installed

Comment: use nvm to switch between versions.

Comment: Also your initial premise is false. The error is just saying that using a globally installed create-react-app is no longer supported so `sudo npm uninstall create-react-app -g` is enough to resolve that issue. No need to get yourself in this situation

Comment: i don't clearly remember how i installed node
is there any other way to remove? @apokryfos

Comment: If you did use a repo then try `sudo apt-get purge node` (without the js)

Comment: Yeah, I've tried those commands and installed them again,
even though it's showing the same

Comment: i've tried "sudo apt-get purge node" too,still the same error